# Issue keeping scaling elements inline

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I have immense difficulty at browser scaling.  Here's my dilemma:

I have a top bar, represented by the following code:

```
    .topbar {
        position: absolute;
        background: #232121;
        min-width: 800px;
        height: 111px;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Inside that topbar element, I have a logo, being created by a background image on an `a` attribute

```
    #logo {
        margin-top: 20px;
        background: #232121 url("images/logo.png") no-repeat right top;
        width:299px;
        height: 76px;
        display:inline-block;
        text-indent: -99999px;
    }
```

I then have a little login form to the right of that:

```
    .userLogin {
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
```

There's also a div called Links...I've almost completely forgot what I'm using it for.

```
    #links {
        width: 100%;
        text-align:center;

    }
```

Here's the full HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="topbar"><div id="links">
       <a href="index.html" id="logo">Logo</a>
        <form action="index.html" method="POST" class="userLogin">
            <input type="text" value="email">
            <input type="password" value="password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" id="signin" />
        </form></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now this creates the elements at the top of the page, and they scale properly when the browser width adjusts.  However, due to the fact that neither element is floating, I can't properly bring down the login form to be aligned with the logo.  I want both elements to be a fixed distance from one another, but I want them to still scale with the width of the page.

I have tried adding padding and margins to both elements...but they both go as one, which doesn't work since I'm trying to only move one down.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Not quite. I want both the logo and the input fields to be on the same line, scaling together.

Comment: Your layout is already doing that http://jsfiddle.net/XSb4D/2/

Comment: Sort of. I want to bring down the login form so that it is centered in between the logo. Right now it rests at the top of the letters, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

The display: inline on the login isn't doing anything, since your using absolute positioning on the logo. I think you should give the login a position then use top: or margin-top: depending on the position type you choose.

Comment: The issue I have with giving the login form a position (such as absolute) is that it ends up being fixed--it doesn't scale with the browser width like the logo does.

Comment: How is the logo scaled - it has set width and height. Are you talking about resizing the browser window or zooming in/out.

Comment: The width and height defined in the logo id is the exact dimensions of the background image, which is the logo.  Right now, scaling the page width causes the logo to move but still remain centered in the page.  I want the login form to do the same thing, but I want it to be aligned center to the right of the logo. Whereas right now it's aligned top.